# Kubernetes ingress controller strict round-robin

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to set up an ingress controller in Kubernetes that will give me strict alternation between two (or more) pods running in the same service.

My testing setup is a single Kubernetes node, with a deployment of two nginx pods.
The deployment is then exposed with a NodePort service.

I've then deployed an ingress contoller (I've tried both [Kubernetes Nginx Ingress Controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) and [Nginx Kubernetes Ingress Controller](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress), separately) and created an ingress rule for the NodePort service.

I edited index.html on each of the nginx pods, so that one shows "SERVER A" and the other "SERVER B", and ran a script that then `curl`s the NodePort service 100 times. It `grep`s "SERVER x" each time, appends it to an output file, and then tallies the number of each at the end.

As expected, curling the NodePort service itself (which uses kube-proxy), I got completely random results-- anything from 50:50 to 80:20 splits between the pods.

Curling the ingress controller, I consistently get something between 50:50 and 49:51 splits, which is great-- the default round-robin distribution is working well.

**However**, looking at the results, I can see that I've curled the same server up to 4 times in a row, but I need to enforce a strict alternation A-B-A-B. I've spent quite a researching this and trying out different options, but I can't find a setting that will do this. Does anyone have any advice, please?

I'd prefer to stick with one of the ingress controllers I've tried, but I'm open to trying a different one, if it will do what I need.

Comment: Hey! Just curious, why do you need specific strict alternation between de pods ?

Comment: Ok, maybe not *need*, but I *want* to :)
In production, calls to one of our services can take minutes at a time. The service is (currently) single-threaded, so if two or three requests are sent to the same pod, they get queued up and eventually time out. 
I'm trying to work out what the logic is for the distribution of those calls by finding out how to set the ingress controller to a strict round-robin alternation.

Comment: @hiiamelliott Did you find what the issue is ? my need and issue is exactly the same.

Comment: @Laukik Yes I did! The short answer is that the Kubernetes Nginx Ingress Controller and the Nginx Kubernetes Ingress Controller (see the links in the OP) aren't the same– one of them does strict round robin; the other does a 50:50 split, but not strict alternation.
We installed the Nginx Ingress Controller from [here:](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/nginx/nginx-ingress)
and then added the annotation `nginx.org/lb-method: “round_robin”` to the ingress resource, which gave us a strict round robin.

Comment: This was a couple of years ago now, and that chart has probably been updated a bit, but hopefully it will give you the result you need.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx default behavior is like **round-robin** only. You can use it to perform most tests on Nginx ingress with different config **tweaks** if required.

There is also other options like you can use the **Istio** **service mesh**.

You can Load balance the traffic as you required by changing the config only

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: bookinfo-ratings
spec:
  host: ratings.prod.svc.cluster.local
  trafficPolicy:
    loadBalancer:
      simple: LEAST_CONN
  subsets:
  - name: testversion
    labels:
      version: v3
    trafficPolicy:
      loadBalancer:
        simple: ROUND_ROBIN
```

Read more at : https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/

& https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#LoadBalancerSettings

however, i would suggest going with `service mesh` only when there is a large cluster implementing for 2-3 services better use the **Nginx** **ingress** or **haproxy-ingress** also good option.

Comment: not sure how you concluded Ngnix does strict round robin cause same problem i have with my cluster and i tested it to find out it repeats hosts at times...

Comment: my bad i think it's not strict but the default behavior is round robin previously it was maybe least_conn with older version.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are 2 versions of ingress controller.

1. Which K8S community has been maintaining which is https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx
2. Which Nginx is maintaining(Opensource & Paid): https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress

The second one seems to be doing strict round robin(still testing) after adding `nginx.org/lb-method: “round_robin”` while the first one does 50:50 aggregate load balancing between replica's

In my opinion its an important difference but with lot of confusion with names, difference between them can be read [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/guide-to-choosing-ingress-controller-part-4-nginx-ingress-controller-options/)

I composed this answer with help of comments from @hiiamelliott...